# How to fix 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int64?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, siamese-network

```
model.fit([training_pairs[:, 0], training_pairs[:, 1]],training_labels,batch_size=64, epochs=10)
```

Epoch 1/10

```
model.fit([training_pairs[:, 0], training_pairs[:, 1]],training_labels,batch_size=64, epochs=10)
```

> TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match
> type int64 of argument 'x'.

```
print(training_labels.dtype)
dtype('int64')

print(training_pairs.dtype)
dtype('float32')
```

As I am not quite familiar with the stackoverflow tool,I have put my notebook link also. I am using tensorflow version 2.4. Much appreciate for your help.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1z4ubLpnvPk6RWGCviCW6z_xMZ5t64gUP?usp=sharing

Comment: Please include your code here and not on Colab

Answer (score 0):

As shown in error, you need to change the label data type as below which is `'int64'`:

```
training_labels = tf.cast(training_labels, tf.float32)
training_labels.dtype
```

OR

```
training_labels=training_labels.astype('float32')
training_labels.dtype
```